# Step Through Visual Studio On Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web, step-through

I am trying to work on this website and I am a bit new to Visual Studio and whatnot. I would like to have a step through action whenever I click on certain icons on the website. Basically it is a lot of code, most of which I am learning, and I need to know where I am sending control when I click certian icons.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the Visual Studio debugger to the IIS or ASP.NET server process hosting your web site? You would then be able to set breakpoints at any line of code, and step from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `Button` that you click must have a `Click Event Handler` in the code behind file. You can go to that code and add a break point by pressing F9 key or use `Debug` > `Toggle Breakpoint`, which makes debugger break when that line of code is executed, after which you can use `F10` key or use `Debug` > `Step Over` to move debugger to next line after executing the current line. While debugging, you can use mouse hover to know values of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Insert break points in your code (click the left margin in the code windows). Your application will then stop, and you'll be sent to Visual Studio to do stuff when the code hits the break points. You also have functions to go through the app line by line from a break point when VS is in debug mode.